# $\sqrt{f}$ has bounded tangential derivatives if $f\in C^{1,1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

This question comes from the paper written by [Guan, Trudinger, and Wang](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-182/issue-1/On-the-dirichlet-problem-for-degenerate-Monge-Amp%C3%A8re-equations/10.1007/BF02392824.full), which can be stated precisely as follows.

> Let $n\geq2$ be an integer and $\Omega\subset\mathbf R^n$ be a bounded
> domain with smooth boundary. Assume $\Omega$ is uniformly convex if necessary. Given $f\in C^{1,1}(\bar\Omega)$
> such that $$f>0\quad\hbox{in $\Omega$.}$$ Does there exist a constant
> $C>0,$ which is at most dependent on $n,~\Omega,$ and
> $\|f\|_{C^{1,1}(\bar\Omega)},$ such that \begin{equation}|\nabla
>  f(x)\cdot\tau(x)|^2\leq Cf(x)\quad\hbox{for all $x\in\partial\Omega$},\label{1}\tag{1}\end{equation}
> where $\tau(x)$ is a unit tangent vector of $\partial\Omega$ at $x.$

In other words, does the tangential derivative $\partial_{\tau}\sqrt f$ have a uniform upper bound?

Actually, authors used in above reference that an incorrect inequality as \begin{equation*}|\nabla f|^2\leq Cf\quad\hbox{in $\Omega.$}\end{equation*} Near the boundary, it is clear that the distance function $d(x)=\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)$ is a counterexample. It seems that all consequences still hold if \eqref{1} is true. If $f(x_0)=0$ for some boundary point $x_0,$ then obviously we can take above $C=1$ at $x_0.$ The difficulty is to control the tangential derivative of $\sqrt f$ if $f(x)>0$ but it is very small.